# select single row of multiple records in One to Many relation tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, one-to-many, offset

In MSSQL, I have two tables with one to many relation.

Tables:

```
tb_Products:
ID
ProductName

tb_Images:
ProductID
MidPath
```

In Stored Procedure, shows products with their images (also shows null records),
And if there is multiple productIDs in tb_Images, it shows a single record.

I can make this work by this Query:

```
declare @rowIndexToFetch int
set @rowIndexToFetch=0

select p.ID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID,c.ParentId,  
    pi.MidPath
    from tb_Products p
    join tb_Categories c
    on p.CategoryID=c.ID
    left outer join tb_Images pi
    on pi.ProductID=p.ID

    where c.ID=3 or c.ParentId=3

    order by pi.ID desc
    offset @rowIndexToFetch rows
    fetch next 1 rows only
```

But, if I use offset and fetch, I no longer can retrieve NULL records from tb_Images. Left outer join does not work anymore.

Example record returns without offset-fetch:

```
ID    ProductName   CategoryID   ParentId  MidPath
154   Chef Ceket     33            3       /cdn/www.sample.com/x
154   Chef Ceket     33            3       /cdn/www.sample.com/y
154   Chef Ceket     33            3       /cdn/www.sample.com/z
1     Eldiven        3             3       NULL
```

with offset-fetch:

```
ID    ProductName   CategoryID   ParentId  MidPath
154   Chef Ceket     33            3       /cdn/www.sample.com/x
```

expected to return:

```
   ID    ProductName   CategoryID   ParentId  MidPath
   154   Chef Ceket     33            3       /cdn/www.sample.com/x
   1     Eldiven        3             3       NULL
```

The problem is, I cannot retrieve null records when I use offset-fetch statement. How can I fix this?

Comment: fetch next 1 rows only

Comment: I already have that. @Mazhar

Comment: do you deliberately limit the result to 1 row with `fetch next 1`?

Comment: Yes. Products with their images. Single record for each productID in the same category. Images table can have multiple imagePaths for a same productID, or no records. I limit multiple records to 1. If no record is in Images table for a ProductID, display ImagePaths as NULL. Left outer was doing this. But with fetch, null records are not coming. @DmitryPolyakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment I think you misanderstand the behaviour of OFFSET FETCH construction. Take another look at manuals.

If you want to get the result described above you could use such a query

```
WITH query AS (
    SELECT 
        p.ID,
        p.ProductName,
        p.CategoryID,
        c.ParentId,  
        pi.MidPath,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY pi.MidPath )-- in your code ORDER set by pi.ID but there's no evidence it exists
    FROM tb_Products p
    JOIN tb_Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.ID
    LEFT JOIN tb_Images pi ON pi.ProductID = p.ID
    WHERE c.ID = 3 or c.ParentId = 3
)
SELECT ID, ProductName, CategoryID, ParentId, MidPath
FROM query
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct p.ID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID,c.ParentId,  
    pi.MidPath
    from tb_Products p
    join tb_Categories c
    on p.CategoryID=c.ID
    left outer join tb_Images pi
    on pi.ProductID=p.ID

    where c.ID=3 or c.ParentId=3
        where c.ID=3 or c.ParentId=3
```

Comment: Thanks, but top 1 returns same result as mine. Ignores null records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in productImage is max. 1 value for each productID.

```
WITH    productImage
      AS ( SELECT   MAX(pi.ID) AS ID
                  , pi.ProductID
           FROM     tb_Images pi
           GROUP BY pi.ProductID
         )
SELECT  p.ID
      , p.ProductName
      , p.CategoryID
      , c.ParentId
      , pi.MidPath
FROM    tb_Products p
        JOIN tb_Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN productImage ON productImage.ProductID = p.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_Images pi ON pi.ID = productImage.ID
WHERE   c.ID = 3
        OR c.ParentId = 3;
```